# String processing in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file from which I am trying to create a pandas DF

```
Name John Doe
Country Wakanda
Month of birth January 1900
social status married

....
```

After every 4 lines a new record similar to that is present. 
The structure of data frame I am trying to create it

```
      Name      Country .    Month of Birth .       social status

0 . John Doe .  Wakanda        January 1900           married
```

Current Approach:

I am using a very inefficient iterative approach to extract the records as list of lists, where each list is a row for the DF.

Is there a better pythonic approach to separate the column names from the values, and extract the values alone.

PS. I am not asking for code. Any suggestion on the approach would be great.

Comment: The field names are always the same? And in the same order?

Comment: @TiagoGomes the field names are the same, but at times one of the field might not have any value, so there it should be NA or null in that position for theDF

Comment: There are certainly other ways to do it, but pre-parsing is probably the simplest and easiest to understand. Another approach would be to convert each line to one row in a pandas Series, then split out the labels and values, then unstack. Might be faster, but certainly more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps an approach could be to have a list of potential matches for each of the entries, and for each entry iterate through this list and strip the key words in the case of a match.

As an example for an individual entry:

```
text = 'Month of birth January 1900'
keys = ['Month of birth', 'Date of birth' 'Birth']
```

When you look for the matches, an option would be to select the shortest string from the list, meaning that more words have matched:

```
min([text.strip(x) for x in keys])
'January 1900'
```

You simply follow this approach for the different fields and build a dataframe from the resulting strings. You could also consider stemming the strings before searching in the keywords. Hope this helps.